# How do I restrict access to particular presentation table under a given subject area in Oracle RPD?

Tags: oracle, obiee

My current configuration in the presentation layer is:

- Generic Sales Subject Area               -->Subject Area

  - Sales Measures                              -->Presentation Table

    - TotalSalesofGoods                      -->Field
  - Costs Measures                              -->Presentation Table

    - CostOfGoods                              -->Field
  - Customer Dimensions                      -->Presentation Table

    - CustomerAccount                        -->Field

I have two roles built, "ShouldSeeGenericSalesSubjectArea" and "ShouldSeeCostFields".

- Permissions

  - "Generic Sales Subject Area"

    - Authenticated User --> No Access
    - ShouldSeeGenericSalesSubjectArea --> Read
    - ShouldSeeCostFields --> Default
  - "Sales Measures"

    - Authenticated User --> Read
    - ShouldSeeGenericSalesSubjectArea --> Default
    - ShouldSeeCostFields --> Default
  - "Cost Measures"

    - Authenticated User --> No Access
    - ShouldSeeGenericSalesSubjectArea --> Default
    - ShouldSeeCostFields --> Read
  - "Customer Dimensions"

    - Authenticated User --> Read
    - ShouldSeeGenericSalesSubjectArea --> Default
    - ShouldSeeCostFields --> Default
  - All Fields have permissions of:

    - Authenticated User --> Read
    - ShouldSeeGenericSalesSubjectArea --> Default
    - ShouldSeeCostFields --> Default

---

- Given two users:

  - UserA

    - User has following roles:

      - ShouldSeeGenericSalesSubjectArea
      - ShouldSeeCostFields
    - User can see everything except the Cost Presentation Table
  - UserB

    - User has following roles:

      - ShouldSeeGenericSalesSubjectArea
    - User can see everything except the Cost Presentation Table

---

- My ultimate goal is:

  - "ShouldSeeGenericSalesSubjectArea" allows access to see the "Generic Sales Subject Area", but does not show cost measure
  - "ShouldSeeCostFields" allows access to see the "Cost Measures" presentation layer.
  - Example:

    - UserA from above should see everything (including "Cost Measures").
    - UserB from above should see everything except the "Cost Measures".

I have tried several different combinations of permission levels to no avail. From my understanding, Oracle security works through taking the path of least restriction. Am I doing something wrong with my permissions on the "Cost Measures" presentation layer? Please let me know if there is anything I can clarify or if you need more info.

Comment: I'd try asking over at the DBA Stack Exchange, it's probably a better venue for this question.

Comment: I'm not sure that would be the best place. I'm trying to implement security through Roles in an Oracle RPD. The oracle RPD is not a database. I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. I had to grant access at the Subject area to cost. This was required because it needed a link down to the table to inherit the security, without it the link was broken.

Answer (score 0):

For the `Cost Measures` Presentation table, setting the role ShouldSeeGenericSalesSubjectArea explicitly to "no access" should achieve what you want.